# Modal com Ajax PHP

Tags: php, ajax, modal, rotas

Olá!

Estou trabalhando com estrutura MVC e rotas e estou tentando abrir um modal com dados de um registro para poder fazer update. Para isso criei uma função no js e coloquei no link do update. Essa função faz uma requisção ajax que através de uma rota me leva até o controller e este me devolve uma página de formulário com os dados preenchidos. Porém, quando clico em qualquer item da minha tabela só abre a rota para o primeiro item. Já tentei algumas soluções usando seletores do jquery, mais ainda sim não vi solução. Ficaria grato se alguém souber o motivo.

Página com a tabela:

```
<tbody class="imagetable">
    <?php foreach($images as $image): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?=$image['id'];?></td>
            <td><?=$image['title'];?></td>
            <td><?=$image['urlimage'];?></td>
            <td><?=$image['slug'];?></td>
            <td>
                <a id="updateimg" href="#" action="dbimages/<?=$image['id'];?>/updatepage" onclick="updateimgitem()">Update</a>
                <a id="deleteimg" href="#" data-action="dbimages/<?=$image['id'];?>/delete">Delete</a>
            </td> 
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?> 
</tbody>
```

JS:

```
function updateimgitem() {
  $.post({
    url: $('#updateimg').attr('action'),
    dataType: 'html',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    beforeSend() {
      $('#modal').find('.modal-body').html('Carregando...');
      $('#modal').modal('toggle');
    },
    success(html) {
      $('#modal').find('.modal-body').html(html);
    },
    complete() {
      $('#modal').modal('toggle');
    },
  });
}
```

PHP:

```
public function update($args) {
    $image = Image::select()->find($args['id']);
    $this->renderSrc(
        'updateimages', 
        [
        'image'=>$image
        ]
    );
}
```

Comment: Você já conferiu se a url está com o Id certo? Se sim, posta o código PHP que recebe esta chamada, nas próximas vezes não faça print dos códigos digite-os, facilite pra quem vai tentar testar etc...

Comment: Opa, valeu a dica, já editei, era a primeira vez que postava. Mas coloquei as partes que interagem agora. Tem o formulário ainda, mas ele só pega os dados do registro e coloca na página, ta funcionando beleza pq quando adiciona um item ele funciona normal. O problema é a url e a rota mesmo, ou alguma coisa no modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que está acontecendo é que quando chama  `url: $('#updateimg').attr('action')` ele recebe o do primeiro elemento com esta ID encontrado (não use a mesma ID em mais de 1 elemento), logo sempre será a primeira linha.

Você pode passar como parametro o ID da linha, ou mudar o Id da tag html, sugiro:

```
function updateimgitem(url) {
  $.post({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'html',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    beforeSend() {
      $('#modal').find('.modal-body').html('Carregando...');
      $('#modal').modal('toggle');
    },
    success(html) {
      $('#modal').find('.modal-body').html(html);
    },
    complete() {
      $('#modal').modal('toggle');
    },
  });
}
```

No HTML:

```
<a id="updateimg" href="#" onclick="updateimgitem('dbimages/<?=$image['id'];?>/updatepage')">Update</a>
```

Passando a url como parametro sem mudar muito seu código.

Comment: Cara, você é fera! Ficou fino. Quebrei a cabeça com algo tão simples, Mas comecei tem pouco tempo e não tinha visto essa ideia ainda, aprendi algo bem legal. Muito Obrigado!

Comment: Opa! Aceita a resposta, e é nóis! hehe